# negate and replacing string with regex in java backslash and quate

Tags: java, regex

I would like to use regex in order to replace '"' value but only if this char isnt followed by backslash

e.g.

```
\"Hello\"  ->  \"Hello\"
"Hello" -> 'Hello'
```

i used the following statement but in deletes the previous char of the '"'

```
[^\\])\"
```

how do i do that in java?

Comment: Is this the only case? Do you have cases such as `\\"Hello"` where the ``\`` is escaped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
string.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\"", "'");
```

In java regex `\\\\` matches a single backslash. So `(?<!\\\\)\"` matches  the double quotes only if it isn't preceded by a backslash.

```
String s1 = "\\\"Hello\\\"";
String s2 = "\"Hello\"";
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\"", "'"));
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\"", "'"));
```

Output:

```
\"Hello\"
'Hello'
```